# Accessing a html file from a menu option does not work when I make a jar or store file

Tags: java, html, jar, store

i have a program that when you select the help link in the menu then your default browser opens and a html page opens. when i create a jar or store file the file does not show up. i have tried :
                                 ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()
but still not working. my html file is stored in a resources folder and the code for the menu is:

```
    if (e.getSource() == helpTopic) {
        try {
            URL url = MenuBar.class.getResource("resources/help.html");
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
        } //end try
        catch (java.io.IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuBar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } //end catch
    }//end if
```

Comment: Did you already check if the structure you expect matches that of the jar file ?

Comment: I believe that the system browser can't display the file if it is packed. What URL you get? Have you tried this URL in browser?

Comment: using a system.out.print on the url i get                                                       file:/C:/Users/home/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Account_pro_v9.7_save/build/classes/resources/help.html

Comment: yes it is there. when i create a jar file it doesn't work however all the icons which are for the menu and are in the same resources folder are ok.